# Angular 2 - Can't bind to 'uib-tooltip' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following line in HTML:

`<div uib-tooltip="{{some.value}}" tooltip-placement="top-left" class=...>`

and I'm getting the above error. I tried doing `[attr.uib-tooltip]=` but that seemed to just make the error worse. i.e.: I still got an error on that snippet, albeit different, as well as all the code around it started throwing errors as well.

Comment: "the above error", "an error"? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the headline of the post: Can't bind to 'uib-tooltip' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Comment: This suggests that you have not imported/configured uib-tooltip correctly.

Comment: Ok. What is the proper way to import/configure uib-tooltip, then?

Comment: Isn't there some doc about that somewhere?

Comment: I looked for one, but I must be searching wrong somehow since I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I was solve similar problem like this:

```
<li [attr.uk-tooltip]="'LeaveConversation' | translate"></li>
```